# Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS)

Tags: json

I'm trying to upload image with some text and number type in html form. In the front end i use angularjs and rest jersey in the backend. my problem is when i try to persist my object "Vehicule" witch it contain a byte[] image. For that i'm using a resource directive in my angular controller, but when i try to submit the form i got this error "Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character ':' (code 0x3a) in base64 content" and i have any idea because i'm a beginner in the angular and rest jersey. For that this is my code :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
public class Vehicule implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column
String marque;
@Column
String nom;
@Column
String numMat;
@Column
Long nbChevaux;
@Column
Long annee;
//@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
@Column(length=100000)
byte[] image=null;
@Column(unique=true) 
Long marqueur=null;
public Long getMarqueur() {
    return marqueur;
}
public void setMarqueur(Long marqueur) {
    this.marqueur = marqueur;
}
public Long getAnnee() {
    return annee;
}
public void setAnnee(Long annee) {
    this.annee = annee;
}
public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getMarque() {
    return marque;
}
public void setMarque(String marque) {
    this.marque = marque;
}
public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}
public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}
public String getNumMat() {
    return numMat;
}
public void setNumMat(String numMat) {
    this.numMat = numMat;
}
public Long getNbChevaux() {
    return nbChevaux;
}
public void setNbChevaux(Long nbChevaux) {
    this.nbChevaux = nbChevaux;
}
    @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Vehicule))
        return false;
    Vehicule other = (Vehicule) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
@Component
@Path("/vehicules")
public class Vehicules {

 private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private VehiculeDao vehiculeDao;
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Vehicule> vehiculesList()

{
        return vehiculeDao.getAll();

}

   @POST
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Vehicule createVehicule(Vehicule vehicule)

{
       this.logger.info("create(): " + vehicule);
       return this.vehiculeDao.save(vehicule);
   }

}

function CreateVehiculeController($scope, $routeParams, $location, VehiculesService)

{

    $scope.vehicule = new VehiculesService();
$scope.save = function() {
$scope.vehicule.$save(function() {
$location.path('/');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.btoa(your_image_as_binary_string);`as value submitted to your controller.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.btoa

Comment: Hello, useful answer. Maybe I'm missing something. If I load the file using `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()`, `window.btoa(FileReader.resul)` and `JSON.stringify(object_with_the_file)`. I got a file that contains `data:text/plain;base64,R2lvcm5pIGR...==` on the server (base64 of a base64 representation?). If I use `FileReader.readAsText()` server receives file correctly. What do I miss?